# Pan and Zoom different objects at the same time - Gestouch. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

I'm using gestouch and it works great, but I cannot quite get it working as needed. I have two touch areas on screen - sprites. The first area controls rotation and zoom/scale of a 3D earth. The second controls panning of a small object. I can pan both areas at the same time, using two hands, but if I am touching anywhere in the second area I'm not able to pinch zoom to scale the 3d earth. If I release my finger in the second area then the zoom gesture works fine. 
This is for multiple people though... so really need full gesture support in multiple areas.

Comment: GesTouch is an abandoned project so you have to modify it yourself if you got the source code or implement your own system.

Comment: @BotMaster abandon yourself :P it's not really growing as I don't use it myself and no one really improving it, but it does the job.

Comment: So Pavel, what do you use then?

Comment: Unfortunately just don't deal with multitouch anymore